# Timezone of SQL Server from UTC to local datetime (via dbplyr)

Tags: r, sql-server, timezone, dbplyr

I'm trying to convert UTC datetime to local timezone and I've tried the following code, but not getting the results I want. Would like the column `today_aest_dttm` to show 2021-06-28 13:57 as dttm format.

Please help

```r
transmute(
  tz = current_timezone(),
  today_getdate = getdate(),
  today_getutcdate = GETUTCDATE(),
  today_cast_utc_as_aest = sql("cast(GETUTCDATE() as datetime) AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time'"),
  today_convert_utc_as_aest = sql("CONVERT(datetime,GETUTCDATE()) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time'"),
  today_aest_dttm = as_datetime(today_convert_utc_as_aest)
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 6]
# Database: Microsoft SQL Server 12.00.2148[connection details]
  tz                               today_getdate       today_getutcdate    today_cast_utc_as_aest         today_convert_utc_as_aest      today_aest_dttm    
  <chr>                            <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>                          <chr>                          <dttm>             
1 (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time 2021-06-27 17:57:40 2021-06-27 17:57:40 2021-06-28 03:57:40.693 +10:00 2021-06-28 13:57:40.693 +10:00 2021-06-28 03:57:40
2 (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time 2021-06-27 17:57:40 2021-06-27 17:57:40 2021-06-28 03:57:40.693 +10:00 2021-06-28 13:57:40.693 +10:00 2021-06-28 03:57:40
3 (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time 2021-06-27 17:57:40 2021-06-27 17:57:40 2021-06-28 03:57:40.693 +10:00 2021-06-28 13:57:40.693 +10:00 2021-06-28 03:57:40
4 (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time 2021-06-27 17:57:40 2021-06-27 17:57:40 2021-06-28 03:57:40.693 +10:00 2021-06-28 13:57:40.693 +10:00 2021-06-28 03:57:40
5 (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time 2021-06-27 17:57:40 2021-06-27 17:57:40 2021-06-28 03:57:40.693 +10:00 2021-06-28 13:57:40.693 +10:00 2021-06-28 03:57:40
6 (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time 2021-06-27 17:57:40 2021-06-27 17:57:40 2021-06-28 03:57:40.693 +10:00 2021-06-28 13:57:40.693 +10:00 2021-06-28 03:57:40
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check the content of `today_aest_dttm` directly in R, as it may be correct internally, just not displaying in the time zone you expect. For example, if the displayed `2021-06-28 03:57:40` represents `"2021-06-28 03:57:40 UTC"` (analogous to what I see when I type `df_local$today_datetime` below), then you effectively have `2021-06-28 13:57:40.693 +10:00` already.

The following uses PostgreSQL (I don't have access to SQL Server), but I think it illustrates how the displayed data may be correct, just not in the time zone you expect (e.g., it's always correct for me, but in UTC rather than in my local EDT).

```r
library(DBI)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

Sys.setenv(TZ="Australia/Sydney")
Sys.timezone()
#> [1] "Australia/Sydney"
pg <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres())

rs <- dbExecute(pg, "SET TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney'")

df <- tbl(pg, sql("SELECT 1 AS temp"))

df %>%
  transmute(today_datetime = sql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")) %>%
  mutate(today_datetime_chr = as.character(today_datetime))
#> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
#> # Database: postgres [igow@/var/run/postgresql:5434/crsp]
#>   today_datetime      today_datetime_chr           
#>   <dttm>              <chr>                        
#> 1 2021-06-28 16:43:44 2021-06-29 02:43:44.241253+10

rs <- dbExecute(pg, "SET TIME ZONE 'UTC'")

df %>%
  transmute(today_datetime = sql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")) %>%
  mutate(today_datetime_chr = as.character(today_datetime))
#> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
#> # Database: postgres [igow@/var/run/postgresql:5434/crsp]
#>   today_datetime      today_datetime_chr          
#>   <dttm>              <chr>                       
#> 1 2021-06-28 16:43:44 2021-06-28 16:43:44.30767+00


rs <- dbExecute(pg, "SET TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'")

df %>%
  transmute(today_datetime = sql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")) %>%
  mutate(today_datetime_chr = as.character(today_datetime))
#> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
#> # Database: postgres [igow@/var/run/postgresql:5434/crsp]
#>   today_datetime      today_datetime_chr           
#>   <dttm>              <chr>                        
#> 1 2021-06-28 16:43:44 2021-06-28 12:43:44.403916-04

df_local <-
  df %>%
  transmute(today_datetime = sql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")) %>%
  collect()

df_local$today_datetime
#> [1] "2021-06-28 16:43:44 UTC"

# Do it again, but from EDT
Sys.setenv(TZ="America/New_York")
Sys.timezone()
#> [1] "America/New_York"
pg <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres())

rs <- dbExecute(pg, "SET TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney'")

df <- tbl(pg, sql("SELECT 1 AS temp"))

df %>%
  transmute(today_datetime = sql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")) %>%
  mutate(today_datetime_chr = as.character(today_datetime))
#> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
#> # Database: postgres [igow@/var/run/postgresql:5434/crsp]
#>   today_datetime      today_datetime_chr           
#>   <dttm>              <chr>                        
#> 1 2021-06-28 16:43:44 2021-06-29 02:43:44.487741+10

rs <- dbExecute(pg, "SET TIME ZONE 'UTC'")

df %>%
  transmute(today_datetime = sql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")) %>%
  mutate(today_datetime_chr = as.character(today_datetime))
#> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
#> # Database: postgres [igow@/var/run/postgresql:5434/crsp]
#>   today_datetime      today_datetime_chr           
#>   <dttm>              <chr>                        
#> 1 2021-06-28 16:43:44 2021-06-28 16:43:44.518931+00

rs <- dbExecute(pg, "SET TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'")

df %>%
  transmute(today_datetime = sql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")) %>%
  mutate(today_datetime_chr = as.character(today_datetime))
#> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
#> # Database: postgres [igow@/var/run/postgresql:5434/crsp]
#>   today_datetime      today_datetime_chr           
#>   <dttm>              <chr>                        
#> 1 2021-06-28 16:43:44 2021-06-28 12:43:44.549623-04

df_local <-
  df %>%
  transmute(today_datetime = sql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")) %>%
  collect()

df_local$today_datetime
#> [1] "2021-06-28 16:43:44 UTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I've figured it out, posting the answer below

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the dbconnect options from dbplyr. specifically, the timezone components below.

```
con <-
dbConnect(
  odbc(),
  driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
  server = "<server details>",
  database = "<database details>",
  UID = <user email>,
  Authentication = "ActiveDirectoryInteractive",
  timezone = Sys.timezone(),
  timezone_out = Sys.timezone()
)
```

The outcome of running the same code above;

```
transmute(
  tz = current_timezone(),
  today_getdate = getdate(),
  today_getutcdate = GETUTCDATE(),
  today_convert_utc_as_aest = sql("CONVERT(datetime,GETUTCDATE()) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time'"),
  today_aest_dttm = as_datetime(today_convert_utc_as_aest))

# Source:   lazy query [?? x 5]
# Database: Microsoft SQL Server 12.00.2148[<connection details>]
  tz                               today_getdate       today_getutcdate    today_convert_utc_as_aest      today_aest_dttm    
  <chr>                            <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>                          <dttm>             
1 (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time 2021-06-29 23:21:40 2021-06-29 23:21:40 2021-06-30 09:21:40.430 +10:00 2021-06-30 09:21:40
2 (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time 2021-06-29 23:21:40 2021-06-29 23:21:40 2021-06-30 09:21:40.430 +10:00 2021-06-30 09:21:40
3 (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time 2021-06-29 23:21:40 2021-06-29 23:21:40 2021-06-30 09:21:40.430 +10:00 2021-06-30 09:21:40
4 (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time 2021-06-29 23:21:40 2021-06-29 23:21:40 2021-06-30 09:21:40.430 +10:00 2021-06-30 09:21:40
5 (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time 2021-06-29 23:21:40 2021-06-29 23:21:40 2021-06-30 09:21:40.430 +10:00 2021-06-30 09:21:40
6 (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time 2021-06-29 23:21:40 2021-06-29 23:21:40 2021-06-30 09:21:40.430 +10:00 2021-06-30 09:21:40
> Sys.time()
[1] "2021-06-30 09:22:07 AEST"
> Sys.timezone()
[1] "Australia/Sydney"
```